# Select subset of list matching condition

Tags: ruby

Assume I am supposed to find the sum of multiples of 7 an 9 up to a limit of 255, this is what I do:

```
(0..255).select do |i|
  i % 7 == 0 || i % 9 == 0
end.inject(:+)
```

I would like to remove the magic numbers and have the method more versatile:

```
divisors = [7,9,13]

(0..255).select do |i|
  divisors.each do |d|
    i % d == 0
  end
end.inject(:+)
```

What is an idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but your code could be more efficient. If k is the number of divisors and n is the upper limit of numbers considered, your algorithm is O(n*k). E.g., say you have 1 number: d and your upper limit is L. Then you want d + 2d + 3d + ... + md where m = floor(L/d). This is equal to d * (1 + 2 + ... + m) = d * m * (m+1) / 2. Done in O(1). For k=2 you can get an answer in O(1) with a bit more work. Larger k will require some thought which I won't bother with since this isn't your question.

Comment: @DaveGalvin thanks for your feedback. Admittably I am not an ace in maths but i'm sure i'll find some useful resources to improve my script - thanks to your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)

```
divisables.map do |d|
  i % d == 0
end.any?
```

HTH

Edit: Alternatively, as @undur_gongor said, you can also use `any?` like

```
divisables.any? { |d| i % d == 0 }
```

Comment: Isn't that functionally identical to `divisables.any? { | d | i % d == 0 }` but less efficient?

Comment: @undur_gongor, Yes you are right. It didn't occur to me. Post edited.